# Why does reference pointing to freed memory work?

Tags: c++

I tried below C++ code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int *p = new int;
    *p = 10;
    int &a = *p;
    delete p;
    a = 20;
    cout<<a<<" ";
    cout<<*p;
    return 0;
}
```

and got output as: 20 20

I thought this may cause runtime error as result of accessing freed memory or some garbage. Probably I got this output as memory location freed by program may haven't been used so far so still retaining old values.

So I thought that it should also happen if I don't use references

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int *p = new int;
    *p = 10;
//  int &a = *p;
    delete p;
//  a = 20;
//  cout<<a;
    cout<<*p;
    return 0;
}
```

but in this case I got output as 0 (checked with multiple runs). Does Reference has anything to do with different outputs?

Compiler: gcc version 4.7.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1)

Comment: It is undefined behavior.

Comment: It appears to work, that's it. You're breaking the rules.

Comment: ok, there is no connection of reference for getting first set of output as 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dereferencing `delete`-d memory is **undefined behaviour** and there's no point figuring out some *patterns* as switching to another compiler or another release of the same compile could break it.

`delete` calls destructors of *non-primitive* types. If you have a `class Integer` wrapper that clears the content when destroyed, you'll see some difference. On *primitive* types, `delete` does not re-initialize the space released. Therefore you might see the original value retained **but this is not guaranteed to work at all and you should never rely on it.**

Answer (score 2):

You are dereferencing released memory. This is undefined behaviour. There is no guarantee what the result will be. It just happens that with your combination of compiler, operating system, and C++ library, the program appears to work.

This is one possible outcome of undefined behaviour.